# How does service constructor get instaniated in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the below `service`:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Service2} from './app.service2';

@Injectable()
export class Service1 {
  constructor(service2:Service2) {
    this.service2 = service2;
  }

  getData() {
    return this.service2.getData();
  }
}
```

I am using this service in one of my component, but i am not sure how does this `service` recieve the `service2` as argument? Tradionally, in JS i do something like this.

```
var s = new Service1(service2);
```

But i don't see anything like this in below plunker, yet it works.
https://plnkr.co/edit/PsySVcX6OKtD3A9TuAEw?p=preview

Can anyone add some light on this.

Answer (score 3):

Angular2 uses [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (DI) to create instances. It creates class instances for components, directives, pipes, and services for you. For this it checks the constructor parameters and its registered list of providers for matchin instances and when DI calls `new Xxx(...)` for you it passes all providers found in its providers list and one was not found it will throw an exception.

If one of the classes has an constructor with parameters, the class needs to have a decorator (one of `@Component()`, `@Directive()`, `@Pipe()`, or `@Injectable()`. This indicates for DI that it needs to analyze the constructor.